# Upload movies with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I get this error when I try to upload movie/video on my site  'You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected'. Here is my code

view:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'MovieController@store', 'files' => true]) !!}
   <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('movie_name', 'Select Movie:') !!}
      {!! Form::file('movie_name', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
   </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $data = $request->all();
   if ($request->hasFile('movie_name')) {
      $file = $request->file('movie_name');
      $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $data[ 'movie_name' ] = $name;
      $destination = '/public/movies';
      $request->file('movie_name')->move(base_path() . $destination, $name);
            return $name;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: chmod ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/2693543

Comment: try to give permission to upload directory via chmod -R 777 uploadsdir

Comment: I have full control on the upload directory. It still shows the same mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Laravel's asset helper method to point to the public folder.

Try this:

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $data = $request->all();
   if ($request->hasFile('movie_name')) {
      $file = $request->file('movie_name');
      $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $data[ 'movie_name' ] = $name;

      $request->file('movie_name')->move(asset('movies'), $name);
            return $name;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Still the same mistake.

Comment: Again, same thing.

Comment: In that case, it's a permissions thing then. Kindly crosscheck the permissions on the folder and if the server has rights to create files or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing '/public/movies' permissions to 775.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 PATH/TO/DIRECTORY
```

Comment: I am using windows, and have full control over permissions.